# How to notify the directive about parameter's change

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have the directive where I am using my variable as parameter:

```
<dm-my-directive var="item" />
```

The directive use this paramter to make some calculation and display information.

The value of `item` is going from web service and it takes some time to initialize the value of `item` in the controller.  When user open page the directive was created with `typeof(item) == undefined` and then the value of `item` set to some `Object` from web service.

I need to know in the directive that the value of `item` was changed to recalculate and redraw the directive.  I am using `$watch` in the directive to observe to the value of `item`, but may be there is a better way to do it ?

**Update:**

Here is the code of the controller:

```
constructor(public $scope: any, 
            public itemResource: app.common.ItemResource) {

    itemResource.itemsByAutoincrementedId(this.itemTypePosition).then((curItem: app.domain.Item) => {
                this.Item = curItem;
            });
}
```

Here is the code of the directive:

```
constructor(public $scope:any) {

      $scope.$watch('item', () => {

         if(typeof($scope.item) === "undefined") return;

         // ... here is business loginc
```

Comment: please provide the code of your directive as well as controller .

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: @demas if you need to know when an input changes in the controller or link function scope.$watch is the way to go.